# How do I refer to actual 'this' inside CoffeeScript fat-arrow callback?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript, scope, this, arrow-functions

The title says it all. When I use the fat-arrow in CoffeeScript, it stores `this` first before calling the function. For example:

```
class myClass
    constructor: ->
        element = $ "#id"
        element.click ->
            @myMethod(@value)
            return
        return

    myMethod: (c)->
        window.console.log(c)
        return
```

would yield

```
var myClass;

myClass = (function() {
  function myClass() {
    var element;
    element = $("#id");
    element.click(function() {
      this.myMethod(this.value);
    });
    return;
  }

  myClass.prototype.myMethod = function(c) {
    window.console.log(c);
  };

  return myClass;

})();
```

Now on line#8 of JavaScript, `this.myMethod` is wrong. In this scope, `this` refers to `element` instead of the class `MyClass`.

However, if on line#4 of CoffeeScript, I replace `element.click ->` by `element.click =>` the line#8 in JavaScript will become `_this.myMethod(_this.val)` where `this` referring to myClass is stored in `_this` before calling the function. But `_this.value` is undefined and even if it were defined, the object I'm trying to access here is `element` (which is referred to by the actual `this` keyword in scope of this function).

How would access the actual `this` now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal in at least three ways. The 1st one would be:

```
class myClass
    constructor: ->
        element = $ "#id"
        element.click =>
            @myMethod(element.value)
            return
        return

    myMethod: (c) ->
        window.console.log(c)
        return
```

And the 2nd:

```
class myClass
    constructor: ->
        element = $ "#id"
        myMethodCallback = (c) => @myMethod(c)
        element.click ->
            myMethodCallback(@value)
            return
        return

    myMethod: (c) ->
        window.console.log(c)
        return
```

The 3rd one is as showed below. I'm not sure about jQuery API usage though, so better check on [appropriate docs page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

```
class myClass
    constructor: ->
        element = $ "#id"
        element.click (event) =>
            @myMethod(event.target.value)
            return
        return

    myMethod: (c) ->
        window.console.log(c)
        return
```

I would prefer the 1st way as it seems to be more straightforward.
This or the other but you need to decide 'which this' you would like to have in scope of the element.click callback. It's not possible to access two 'thises' at the same time.

By the way. All those return statements seems unnecessary. The shortest working solution would look like:

```
class myClass
    constructor: ->
        element = $ "#id"
        element.click => @myMethod(element.value)

    myMethod: (c) -> window.console.log(c)
```

Comment: A couple more options: (1) The old `that = @` trick still works in CoffeeScript, (2) The click handler will still get an event passed as an argument even when it is fat-arrowed, you should be able extract the clicked element from that event.

Comment: @muistooshort You are right. I was thinking about adding 3rd example with `that = @`, but that's the same as using fat arrow. Well almost the same, depends on context. I haven't been using jQuery for some time now so didn't think about your another suggestion. Of course you can access click subject from the event passed as argument jQuery API.

Comment: The main difference between `that = @` and `=>` is that `that = @` gives you access to both `@`s (that's a bit of a tongue twister :). I'm not criticizing, just figure that more options are better (that's my upvote up there).

Comment: That's why I wrote that it's _almost_ the same. Fat arrow was introduced to avoid need of using `that = this` trick, which was necessary in javascript. So using it and the old trick at the same time seems to be quite hacky. Anyway it's probably still cleaner than defining a method callback the line above, I guess (my 2nd example). Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: Thank you. I had all these options in mind. I was asking whether there is another symbol/keyword that stores the actual `this` inside the fat-arrow callback. I know all these methods. And the one discussed in comments i.e. `that = @` is the one I use most frequently. Also, 2nd and 3rd methods in the answer above are applicable if I am using jQuery and I have precached the `element`, however I used that just as an example. This was kind of a dumb question I think now. Haha. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Nah, it's not a stupid question. Scope of `this` reference is  probably the most confusing thing in CoffeeScript, especially for those who come to this language without JS background. And I know a few programmers who haven't got anything in common with JS but they are using (and liking) CoffeeScript. Mostly they just always use fat arrow to avoid confusion. Well, it's just more familiar doing so to someone having background in regular OO language like f.g. JAVA. Some advantages of JS/CS are lost with such approach though.