# CoffeeScript: access actual @(this) in fat arrow function =>

Tags: coffeescript

I found similar questions like this.
[How do I refer to actual 'this' inside CoffeeScript fat-arrow callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555422/how-do-i-refer-to-actual-this-inside-coffeescript-fat-arrow-callback)

I know how to overcome this kind of situations with a lot of ways, but I just want to make sure the actual grammar.

The question is,
Can I access actual this in => function?
@ and this keyword compiled to _this variable to bind parent this in fat arrow function. 
So the actual this in => function is just hided by _this keyword?

Thanks.

Comment: The implementation of `=>` has changed a few times and will probably change again. The documentation doesn't say that you can use `_this` and in general, you can't depend on CoffeeScript's internally generated JavaScript variables having any particular names at all. The duplicate still stands.

Comment: So the way to access actual 'this' in the fat arrow for the coffeeScript is, nothing for now, right? I just wanna confirm this. thanks.

Comment: Right, there's no special way to do that.